# Render Backbone view dynamically

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following Backbone View :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  id : 'myview'+atrs.i, //i is the property of atrs passed as parameter to view

  initialize: function(atrs) {
   $('#'+atrs.DOMid).append(this.$el);
  }
});
```

I am considering that a HTML Element with id `DOMid` already exists in Body before initialising the View. Then I initialise the view as :

```
new MyView({DOMid:'mydiv',i:2});
```

But I get the error : `cannot read property i of undefined`

I also tried :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(atrs) {
   this.id = 'myview'+atrs.i;
   $('#'+atrs.DOMid).append(this.$el);
  }
});
```

In this case view is generated but with no any id attribute in it.

How do i approach my objective.

Comment: Have you tried to `.append(this.render().$el)` instead `.append(this.$el)`?

Comment: @TMichel No change in result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set MyView's id dynamically, you'll have to use a function:

```
id: function() { return 'myview'+atrs.i; },
```

But a cleaner approach would be to use the MyView's designated args on instantiation:

```
new MyView({el:'#mydiv',id:'myview2'});
```